# Почему возникает ошибка "Error: expected identifier or '('"?

Tags: c, cs50

Пример взят из CS50. Я не понимаю почему это не работает?

> ```
> Error:expected identifier or '('  
>     1 error generated.
> ```

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)    
{
    printf("%i!\n", i);
}
```

Comment: `int main ...`? И вопрос на русский переведите.

Comment: потому что нужно писать программу полностью, а не один цикл. То есть, как минимум ещё `int main()..`

Comment: Это весь код? очевидно не стоит запускать циклы в глобальном пространстве. Нужно делать это в контексте некоторой функции.

Comment: Пример взят из задачника и там он позиционировался как готовый код.
Если не сложно, объясните мне так, словно общаетесь с дауном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Типичная минимальная программа на Си имеет вид

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  // тут ваш код (это комментарий)

  return 0; // 0 это код успешного завершения, он возвращается в ОС
}
```

вставьте свой цикл вместо (или после (можно перед)) комментария и запускайте.

Современный компилятор (С11 ?) автоматически сформирует для такой программы код завершения  0 (успех). Если у вас такой компилятор, то вы с легкой душой можете удалить последний оператор (`return 0;`) (или закомментировать его).

Ранее (правильную) программу надо было завершать оператором `return 0;` (или вызовом функции `exit(0);`) для передачи в ОС кода завершения (от 0 до 255).

Строка `#include <stdio.h>` (*standard buffered input/output*) подключает ввод-вывод. Также крайне полезным будет добавить в начале программы аналогичные директивы

```
#include <stdlib.h> // standard library definitions -- подключает более полусотни различных часто используемых функций 
#include <string.h> // string operations -- подключает функции для работы со строками
```

Подробнее о содержимом подключаемых файлов можно прочесть в `man stdio.h`, `man stdlib.h` и `man string.h`.

Comment: вообще то main - функция и вставить return 0 - правило хорошего тона. Да, некоторые компиляторы добавляют его. Но давайте не будем молодежь обучать плохому.

Comment: @KoVadim, OK, поправлю (сам не так давно узнал об этом -))

Comment: return(0), я так понимаю, командует эту функцию завершить.
А с помощью какой команды её можно зациклить?

Comment: @PavelBobrov, совершено верно. Между прочим, выходить по `return` можно из любой точки функции (не только в самом конце). Но злоупотреблять этим не стоит. Хорошая функция максимально "линейна" (тогда она проще для восприятия человеком)

Comment: @PavelBobrov, не уверен, что правильно понял ваше пожелание ее зациклить, но можно вызвать ее саму из себя (это называется рекурсия). Безусловно, в таком виде эта рекурсия "бесконечна" и вскоре (по исчерпанию ресурсов системы) будет аварийно завершена ОС.

Comment: @KoVadim: С точностью до наоборот: правило хорошего тона - это как раз помнить, что языки С и С++ не требуют `return 0` именно в функции `main` и гарантируют возврат `0` в случае нормального завершения `main` без `return` (нет, не "некоторые компиляторы", а именно спецификации языков гарантируют это). Ошибкой это, конечно, не будет, но именно в минимальных примерах этот лишний `return 0` особенно сильно режет глаз.

Comment: Хотя я понимаю, почему ваша "типичная минимальная программа" включает `<stdio.h>` (для "Hello World"), но все таки в реальности `<stdlib.h>` уместнее. Если уж включать `<stdio.h>` в "минимальную программу", то вместе с `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Большое спасибо что так точно и развернуто все описываете)
Предположим, что функция не считает до 49, как эта. А запрашивает число, а после ввода говорит какое это число (положительно, отрицательное, или ноль). Запускаешь ,вводишь число - получаешь ответ. И после этого её снова нужно запускать. Можно ли как-то избавиться от необходимости запускать её каждый раз?

Comment: @AnT, главное тут не превратить краткий ответ в "краткий курс"... -)

Comment: @PavelBobrov, конечно, все это легко программируется. Но, как-то мне кажется, что полезней будет сначала прочесть всего-то [пару сотен страничек](http://people.toiit.sgu.ru/Sinelnikov/PT/C/Kern_Ritch.pdf), а уже потом задавать вопросы.

Comment: *закомментарить* // первый раз такой вариант вижу

Comment: @alexolut, *закомментировать* не режет?

Comment: @avp Благодарю)